# scrpage2 headers in classic thesis

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, classicthesis, scrpage2

I am trying to modify the headers in the classicthesis document class, which uses {scrpage2} of koma-script. What I want to have is no number in the sections header on the odd page. I have looked on the questions here and found some answer that I tried. However, the result is that there still appear numbers, albeit 0 for the section and the chapter number. (example: 0.0 in the introduction, and 1.0, 2.0 etc. for chapter 1, chapter 2).

Also, I would like to make the unnumbered chapters such as "Introduction", "Conclusion", and "bibliography" in small caps as the regular chapters.

MWE:

```
  \documentclass{scrbook}

\PassOptionsToPackage{automark}{scrpage2}
\RequirePackage{scrpage2} 
\clearscrheadings
\setheadsepline{0pt}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@nochapters}}
    {\relax}
    {\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}   {\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}} 
\lehead{\mbox{\llap{\small\thepage\kern2em}\headmark\hfil}}
\rohead{\mbox{\hfil{\headmark}\rlap{\small\kern2em\thepage}}}
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\small}  
   \DeclareRobustCommand{\fixBothHeadlines}[2]{} 
    \def\toc@heading{%
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{@nochapters}}%
        {\section*{\contentsname}}%nochapters
        {\chapter*{\contentsname}}%chapters
        \@mkboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}}

    \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

I get these results:
[image: odd number, section, caps, but chapter number and zero]
[image: even page, no chapter, not in caps]

Comment: Please clarify: Where is the code taken from? Copied from `classicthesis.sty` or already altered by you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Where can I put my mew? I don't have enough space in the comment here.

Comment: The code is copied from `classicthesis.sty` and compiled into a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to make it work, but it's by specifying manually every single entry (which is fastidious). I enter the following:

```
    \addchap{Introduction: On Cosmopolitanism}
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Introduction:}}}{\MakeUppercase{\spacedlowsmallcaps{On Cosmopolitanism}}}
```

Same for the section:

```
    \addsec{Cosmopolitan theory}
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Introduction: On Cosmopolitanism}}}{\MakeUppercase{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Cosmopolitan Theory}}}
```

Comment: You could convert these into your own commands and use these instead: `\newcommand*{\mychap}[2]{\addsec{#1}\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#2}}}{\MakeUppercase{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#2}}}}` and analoguesly for sections.

Comment: Thanks. Where do you mean I should put these commands?

Comment: Both `\newcommand…` into preamble, best place is where you already have definitions for chapters and/or sections. In document body you replace these two lines for every chapter/section with the according new command.